# Named column formulas in an org mode table

Tags: emacs, formula, org-mode

I have the following emacs org mode table.

```
|---+-----+-----+-----+-----|
| ! | foo | bar | baz | duu |
| # |  -5 |   2 |     |     |
```

To calculate the values of baz and duu I have the formulas

```
#+TBLFM: $4=vsum($foo..$bar)::$duu=vsum($foo..$bar)
```

When I reevaluate all formulas with C-u C-c C-c or C-u C-c *, the value of baz is computed fine, but the value of duu remains empty. Since the only difference between the formulas for baz and duu is that the former uses a number reference and the latter a named reference, I assume that one cannot use named column reference on the left side of the assignment operator. However I find it rather inconvenient as I don't want to hardcode the column numbers because I might need to add/remove columns in the future.

Is there a way to create a column formula that uses names for all columns involved?

Comment: I don't think you can use a name reference on the LHS, but you can use something like `$>` to refer to the last column, `$>>` for the previous one etc. That might help if you insert columns in the middle.

Comment: Thanks. Yes it does help in cases when the left-hand side is close to one of the edges of the table. But it is still unclear what to do if a column you are assigning to is somewhere in the middle. I was wondering if there is a workaround for this problem, as I doubt that using direct numbered references is the right way to go.

Comment: Here's [the discussion on a bug](http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/emacs-orgmode/2018-05/threads.html#00433) that may possibly relate to this question (no promises).

Comment: Seems to be related, although not the same. In my formula the $ sign is there, it just does not work properly.